# Codeigniter - AngularJS routing causes 404

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I try to use Codeigniter with AngularJS routing, and it's working, but I need without hash.
I use this code:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', { templateUrl: 'assets/js/partials/blank.html' }).
        when('/:name', { templateUrl: 'assets/js/partials/blank.html', controller: PagesController }).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

but when I refresh the page, jumps to 404.

Comment: In order it to work in HTML5 mode, you need to setup your webserver (.htaccess) to respond with index page for all requests (non-status resourses).

Comment: Could you explain a bit precisely?
I tried with this .htaccess, but always causes 404.
`code`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
</IfModule>`code`

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I finally figured out.
The htaccess was good, just I had to change the route of 404 page within codeigniter.
routes.php:
$route['default_controller'] = "project_name";
$route['404_override'] = 'project_name';
Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately not the perfect. When I type a page, which is not exists `code`($routeProvider.when('/:name',`code`...etc, I have infinite loop, Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

You can always set the `$route['404_override'] = ''` to you default controller. This way it will not be 404.