# ui-router with codeigniter gives 404 when refreshing the page or pasting the URL with html5mode(true)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter, angular-ui-router

I'm using codeiginiter with angular-js and ui-router just like in [this seed project](https://github.com/rmcdaniel/angular-codeigniter-seed) , and i wanted to remove the `/#/` from the url, so i used:

`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

in my app.js `.config` and I also added `<base href="/">` on `index.php`.

Now I don't have the `/#/` on the URL but when I refresh the page I get a 404, also, if I copy a working URL(which I get to it from the main view) and paste it in the URL line I also get a 404 message.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374407/codeigniter-angularjs-routing-causes-404) but i don't want to override my 404, i don't think that's wise.

and ideas?

Comment: Need to handle the server side http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request/16570533#16570533

Comment: thanks @xkcd149, i posted how i solved the issue and gave you credit there, thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [xkcd149](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5651026/xkcd149)'s link to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request/16570533#16570533) I figured out that changing the routing in the codeiginiter 3 so that you would always go through your CI root controller should look like this:

on `/application/config/routes.php`:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home'; //can have any name you want
$route['exampleUrl'] = 'home';
$route['anotherUrl/(:any)'] = 'home'; //this url passes a parameter
$route['anotherUrl/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'home'; //this one passes 2 parameters
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Hey! I'm going through the same problem. I reached what you said above so far, but when I try to make a requisition (like "people/get") I get the "home" view... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume that the default on your routing is `'/'` so you might have a problem with the URL you are trying to access.